# transferring a website to a subdomain, all attached files returning a 404 error

Tags: ftp, subdomain

While making some updates to a website, I moved my work to a local server. When I was ready to test the site online I moved the site to a subdomain of my client's host. I uploaded the site's files to the subdomain and all of the attached style folders, scripts and images are returning a 404 page not found error. I've updated the paths multiple times with no luck.

www.testing123.emcfintech.com

Any ideas on how to work through this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Links are not referenced correctly. For example your script

```
<script src="TESTING123.emcfintech.com/js/superfish.js"></script>
```

will result in a http://www.testing123.emcfintech.com/TESTING123.emcfintech.com/js/superfish.js lookup, which returns 404.

Either reference your links absolute

```
<script src="https://TESTING123.emcfintech.com/js/superfish.js"></script>
```

or relative

```
<script src="/js/superfish.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, my paths were all jacked. Thanks for the direction, will update my pathways!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try taking the css file out of the current folder and either adding it to another folder or leaving it in the root?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need more informations about your setup. Looking the source code of the page located at testing123.emcfintech.com shows you're wrongly linking files.

For exemple :

```
<link href="TESTING123.emcfintech.com/js/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Should be :

```
<link href="js/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Are you sure the files you're trying to access are in the right directory, or do you use a .htaccess file on your server ?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, my paths were all jacked. Thanks for the direction!